# OpenCV+Python getting this error when trying to run the code on bigger images

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, image-processing

I am getting this error when running my code through a set of big images of 5472 x 3648 dimension(4.4mb) . The code is working fine when my images were around 1437 x 1243 dimension, I can run through all images and save it.

**Notice:** You can see with bigger images, I still managed to run the first file and save it to 1771, it only shown error and stop the run halfway through 1772.

Is there anyway which I can process my images using this algorithm without needing to resize the images dimension? I was trying to aligned all my images with reference to file 1770.  I suspect it might be a memory/RAM`enter code here` issue or there might be something wrong with my algorithm which I could further simplify it. Any suggestion or advice on this issue????

PC spec: using 8GB RAM

Error message:

```
RESTART: C:\Users\310293649\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Picture Alignment.py 
1771
1772
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\310293649\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Picture Alignment.py", line 65, in <module>
    alignment()
  File "C:\Users\310293649\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Picture Alignment.py", line 46, in alignment
    (cc, warp_matrix) = cv2.findTransformECC(im1_gray, im2_gray, warp_matrix, warp_mode, criteria)
cv2.error: D:\Build\OpenCV\opencv-3.2.0\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp:433: error: (-215) u != 0 in function cv::Mat::create
```

Below is my code :

```
import os, sys
import cv2
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

path = "C:\\Users\\310293649\\Desktop\\BeforeAlignment\\"
path1 = "C:\\Users\\310293649\\Desktop\\AfterAlignment\\"

def alignment():
    for i in range(1771,1800):
        # Read the images to be aligned
        im1 =  cv2.imread(path + 'IMG_1770.jpg')
        im2 =  cv2.imread(path + 'IMG_%d.jpg' %(i))
        print(i)

        # Convert images to grayscale
        im1_gray = cv2.cvtColor(im1,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        im2_gray = cv2.cvtColor(im2,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        # Find size of image1
        sz = im1.shape

        # Define the motion model
        warp_mode = cv2.MOTION_TRANSLATION

        # Define 2x3 or 3x3 matrices and initialize the matrix to identity
        if warp_mode == cv2.MOTION_HOMOGRAPHY :
            warp_matrix = np.eye(3, 3, dtype=np.float32)
        else :
            warp_matrix = np.eye(2, 3, dtype=np.float32)

        # Specify the number of iterations.
        number_of_iterations = 10000;

        # Specify the threshold of the increment
        # in the correlation coefficient between two iterations
        termination_eps = 1e-10;

        # Define termination criteria
        criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS | cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_COUNT, number_of_iterations,  termination_eps)

        # Run the ECC algorithm. The results are stored in warp_matrix.
        (cc, warp_matrix) = cv2.findTransformECC(im1_gray, im2_gray, warp_matrix, warp_mode, criteria)

        if warp_mode == cv2.MOTION_HOMOGRAPHY :
            # Use warpPerspective for Homography 
            im2_aligned = cv2.warpPerspective (im2, warp_matrix, (sz[1],sz[0]), flags=cv2.INTER_LINEAR + cv2.WARP_INVERSE_MAP)
        else :
            # Use warpAffine for Translation, Euclidean and Affine
            im2_aligned = cv2.warpAffine(im2, warp_matrix, (sz[1],sz[0]), flags=cv2.INTER_LINEAR + cv2.WARP_INVERSE_MAP);

        cv2.imwrite(path1 + "aligned_IMG_%d.jpg" % (i), im2_aligned)
        cv2.waitKey(0)

alignment()
```

Comment: Does the "Python36-32" in the path accurately hint at it being a 32bit build? (Since then the 8GB is kinda irrelevant, as it can never address that much anyway). | It [does look](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3.2.0/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp#L433) like an allocation error. | "5472 x 3648 dimension(4.4mb)" -- 4.4 MB when encoded. It's roughly 20 megapixel and you load it as BGR (that's about 60 MB of data), then convert to grayscale (20MB). | Time to dig through some [code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/ab9bbf645cab397d1a5d99ed1a849d3ddd395fa2/modules/video/src/ecc.cpp#L312)...

Comment: So, if you look through the implementation of `findTransformECC`, you'll notice a number if temporary matrices allocated. I can see at least 10 `Mat`s of the same dimensions as input images, using 32bit floats. At 4 bytes per pixel, that's ~ 80MB each. A rough guess would be it uses around 1GB of temporaries. Add some memory fragmentation, and IMHO there's a good chance you'll run into trouble with a 32bit app.

Comment: BTW, it seems `im1` and `im1_gray` could be created outside the loop, no point loading/converting the same thing over and over. Also, a 'waitKey' without `imshow` seems a bit pointless.

Comment: You should use `cv2.imread(path + 'IMG_1770.jpg', 0)` to load the image as grayscale instead of loading as BGR and then converting to grayscale

Comment: @ShawnMathew Might as well, although just for `im1`. Can't imagine eliminating one 60MB array will help too much tho.

Comment: @DanMašek I agree. I just think it's an unnecessary two extra lines when you can just read as grayscale. Also, I agree with you in that the code should be compiled for Python 64bit.

Comment: @ShawnMathew thank you for your input too...i tried your method to load it with 0 but it will save my final images as greyscale instead of color images.

Comment: DanMašek thank you for your suggestion. I managed to run it without any error using 64bits. I guess the images is just too big for 32bits numpy to handle. But the downside is it wasnt really time efficient even when I am able to run it. Took quite a long time to finish aligned all 99 images

Comment: @DanMašek one thing I dont understand are I realised the saved images file size were cut down by half to only 2-3 MB. Is this normal or does it imply that there are images quality loss/color loss in my images while trying to align them?

Comment: @MingKhaw Rather than numpy, it's the OpenCV algorithm, which just requires a large amount of temporary storage. Regarding time -- going from 1437x1243 to 5472x3648 means ~11x larger input, so even a simple linear algorithm would be expected to run ~11x longer. Linear complexity is IMHO an optimistic expectation, there's a good chance it's worse than that. Regarding size: Ya, you use JPEG, and that's a lossy format. `imwrite` uses default quality of 95 (i.e. not the best). Each time you recompress you lose something. Use something like PNG -- the files will be bigger, but there's no loss.